# Even if my thread count is 4 only 2 threads is working, classes from others 'test' is not executed in parallel

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, selenium-grid, testng.xml

My first 'test' has 2 classes and my second 'test' has 3 classes. If my thread count is 4, Only 2 classes in first 'test' is executed in parallel. Instead i want 2 classes from first 'test' and 2 classes from second 'test' to be executed. As my thread count is 4. In my .xml i have mentioned parallel = 'classes' and threadcount = 4.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" parallel="classes" thread-count="3" >           
 <test name="Module1">
    <classes>
    <class name="classM11" />
    <class name="classM12" />
    </classes>
  </test>
  <test name="Module2">
    <classes>
    <class name="classM21" />
    <class name="classM22" />  
    <class name="classM23" />  
    </classes> 
  </test>  
  <test name="Module3">
    <classes>
    <class name="classM31" />
    <class name="classM32" />  
    <class name="classM33" />  
    </classes> 
  </test>  
</suite>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with `parallel` attribute at suite and test node level as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" parallel="tests" thread-count="3" >           
 <test name="Module1"  parallel="classes">
    <classes>
    <class name="classM11" />
    <class name="classM12" />
    </classes>
  </test>
  <test name="Module2"  parallel="classes">
    <classes>
    <class name="classM21" />
    <class name="classM22" />  
    <class name="classM23" />  
    </classes> 
  </test>  
  <test name="Module3"  parallel="classes">
    <classes>
    <class name="classM31" />
    <class name="classM32" />  
    <class name="classM33" />  
    </classes> 
  </test>  
</suite>
```

Here, at suite level `parallel` value specified to `tests` and at test node level specified to `classes`. Furthermore, you can try with different combination of `thread-count` at suite and test node level in addition to `parallel` attribute.